# Prove that $x_n = (-1)^n \frac {3n + 2} {n + 1}$ is divergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that the sequence {${x_n}$} to be defined by $x_n = (-1)^n \frac {3n + 2} {n + 1}$ is divergent.

Also, you can assume without proof that $\lim{n\to\infty}$ $\frac{3n+2}{n+1} = 3 $

Proposed Solution: (by contradiction)

Given that there were a limit $x$, then for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ we expect an $M$ to satisfy the divergence definition. Suppose such an $M$ exists. Then for $n\geq M$ we need to compute:

$\frac{1}{2} > |x_n - x| = |1 - x|$ and $\frac{1}{2} > |x_{n+1} - x| = |-1 - x|$

- Do I do the following next? : plug in $x_{2n} = \frac{6n}{2n+1}$ and $x_{2n+1} = -\frac{6n+3}{2n+2} $
- Then conclude this? : $\lim{n\to\infty}$ $x_{2n} = 3$ and $\lim{n\to\infty}$ $x_{2n+1} = -3$
- Therefore, $\frac{1}{2} \ngtr |1 - 3|$ and $\frac{1}{2} \ngtr |-1 - (-3) |$ ?

Comment: There are two subsequences $x_{2k}, k=1,2,...$ and $x_{2k+1}, k=1,2,...$ having different limits, so the sequence $x_n, n=1,2,...$ has no limit.

Comment: Alt. hint: the limit of $\,\big|x_{n+1}-x_n\big|\,$ is not $\,0\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the limit exists and call it $x$. Thus, for $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{2}$, there is a $n$ such that $|x_n - x| < \dfrac{1}{2}, |x_{n+1} - x| < \dfrac{1}{2}\implies |x_{n+1} - x_n| < 1$. If $n$ is even, then $|x_n - x_{n+1}| = \left|\dfrac{3n+2}{n+1} + \dfrac{3n+5}{n+2}\right| > 2$, contradiction. The case $n$ is odd is similar. So $x$ can't exist.

Comment: Wang. Why not show right away that it is not Cauchy?

Comment: @Peter Szilard: I wanted to use the low tech way .

Comment: Wang YeFei. Well done +1.

Answer (score 1):

Overkill?

$x_n=(-1)^n(3-1/(n+1));$

$x_n$ is not Cauchy.

Let $\epsilon =1/2;$

Assume there exists a $n_0$ s.t.

for $m\ge n \ge n_0$

$|x_m-x_n| <1/2;$

For even $n (\ge 2)$ :

$|x_{n+1}-x_n|=$

$|-3+1/(n+2)-3 +1/(n+1)|$

$=|6-(1/(n+2)+1/(n+1)) |>$

$5>1/2$, and we are done.